# Extract face images from a large number of photos in Photo Library using CIDetector

Tags: swift, objective-c, uikit, core-graphics, core-image

I am trying to iterate over images in Photo Library and extract faces using CIDetector. The images are required to keep their original resolutions. To do so, I taking the following steps:

**1- Getting assets given a date interval (usually more than a year)**

```
func loadAssets(from fromDate: Date, to toDate: Date, completion: @escaping ([PHAsset]) -> Void) {
        fetchQueue.async {
            let authStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
            if authStatus == .authorized || authStatus == .limited {
                let options = PHFetchOptions()
                options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate >= %@ && creationDate <= %@", fromDate as CVarArg, toDate as CVarArg)
                options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
                let result: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: options)
                var _assets = [PHAsset]()
                result.enumerateObjects { object, count, stop in
                    _assets.append(object)
                }
                completion(_assets)
            } else {
                completion([])
            }
        }        
    }
```

where:

```
let fetchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
```

**2- Extracting faces**

I then extract face images using:

```
func detectFaces(in image: UIImage, accuracy: String = CIDetectorAccuracyLow, completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
        
        faceDetectionQueue.async {
            var faceImages = [UIImage]()
            let outputImageSize: CGFloat = 200.0 / image.scale
            guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image),
                  let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: accuracy]) else { completion(faceImages); return }
            
            let faces = faceDetector.features(in: ciImage) // Crash happens here
             
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            
            for face in faces {
                group.enter()
                if let face = face as? CIFaceFeature {
                    let faceBounds = face.bounds
                    let offset: CGFloat = floor(min(faceBounds.width, faceBounds.height) * 0.2)
                    let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -offset, left: -offset, bottom: -offset, right: -offset)
                    let rect = faceBounds.inset(by: inset)
                    let croppedFaceImage = ciImage.cropped(to: rect)
                    let scaledImage = croppedFaceImage
                        .transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: outputImageSize / croppedFaceImage.extent.width,
                                                           y: outputImageSize / croppedFaceImage.extent.height))
                    faceImages.append(UIImage(ciImage: scaledImage))
                    group.leave()
                } else {
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
            
            group.notify(queue: self.faceDetectionQueue) {
                completion(faceImages)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

where

```
private let faceDetectionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "face detection queue",
                                      qos: DispatchQoS.background,
                                      attributes: [],
                                                   autoreleaseFrequency: DispatchQueue.AutoreleaseFrequency.workItem,
                                      target: nil)
```

I use the following extension to get the *image* from assets:

```
extension PHAsset {
    var image: UIImage {
        autoreleasepool {
            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            var thumbnail = UIImage()

            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pixelWidth, height: pixelHeight)
            options.isSynchronous = true
            options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
            options.resizeMode = .exact
            options.normalizedCropRect = rect
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            
            manager.requestImage(for: self, targetSize: rect.size, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
                if let result = result {
                    thumbnail = result
                } else {
                    thumbnail = UIImage()
                }
                })
            
            return thumbnail
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine for a few (usually less that 50) assets, but for more number of images it crashes at:

```
let faces = faceDetector.features(in: ciImage) // Crash happens here
```

I get this error:

```
validateComputeFunctionArguments:858: failed assertion `Compute Function(ciKernelMain): missing sampler binding at index 0 for [0].'
```

If I reduce the size of the image fed to detectFaces(:) e.g. 400 px, I can analyze a few hundred images (usually less than 1000) but as I mentioned, using the asset's image in the original size is a requirement. My guess is it has something to do with a memory issue when I try to extract faces with CIDetector.
Any idea what this error is about and how I can fix the issue?

Comment: Are you, by chance, keeping all those extracted face images in memory? If yes, this might quickly exceed your app's working memory quickly so that Core Image can't allocate new memory for its tasks.

Comment: @FrankRupprecht no, I am not keeping the full-size images.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess what could be the issue here, so here are a few ideas:

- A `CIDetector` is an expensive object, so try only to create a single one and re-use it for each image.
- Use a single shared `CIContext` for performing all Core Image operations (more below). Also, pass that to the `CIDetector` on `init`. The context manages all resources needed for rendering an image. Sharing it will allow the system to re-use as many resources as possible.
- The `UIImage(ciImage:)` constructor is really tricky. You see, `CIImages` are basically just *recipes* for creating an image, not actual bitmaps. They store the instructions for rendering the image. It takes a `CIContext` to do the actual rendering. When initializing a `UIImage` with a `CIImage`, you let UIKit decide how and when to render the image, which, in my experience, caused a lot of issues for other users here on StackOverflow.
  Instead, you can use the shared `CIContext` I mentioned above to render the image first before you make it a `UIImage`:

```swift
let renderedImage = self.ciContext.createCGImage(scaledImage, from: scaledImage.extent).map(UIImage.init)
```

Comment: Thanks! I applied the changes you suggested. The third specifically improves the performance, however, it still crashes at the same line, except the crash happens after analysing more photos. Any idea what other improvements I can do? What do you think about let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)?

Comment: PS, I am not keeping any images. The original photo from Photo Library is used to extract faces and face images are then inputs to an CoreML model. Why would the used memory be increasing so dramatically? In debugger, it starts from 250 MG ---> 1.6 GB --> Crash

Comment: Hmm, can you please run it in Instruments using the “Leaks” profiler and check what kinds of objects start accumulating over time?

Comment: The responsible caller appear to be CMPhotoCreateImageSurface. It keeps creating object of this type. Could you please check this out? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ABL0kHUC_1XztHlo300vfyQkyI-1X8dD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems something keeps a reference to each image you load from Photos. Maybe you can use the Memory Graph in Xcode to check who references all those IOSurfaces.

Comment: Hey Frank, I managed to (kinda) fix it. Instead of making the ciImage in detectFaces function, I get it from the PHAsset extension inside autorelease (instead of getting the UIImage of asset, I get the CIImage). So I pass the CIImage as argument of detectFaces instead of UIImage. It uses much less memory and so far no crashed has happened. Needs to be tested on different devices though.

Comment: The CPU usage is very high though and at some points goes to 300%! Any idea how to manage that?

Comment: Well, you are doing a lot of heavy work with running face detection on so many images. I'm not sure how to mitigate that without adding artificial throttles somewhere.